# Django Rest Framework: How call check_object_permissions() with APIView or GenericAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to allow only object creators to be able to see their object.

So, I want to verify that the user is equal to the `created_by` field of the object.

I use only `APIView` or `GenericAPIView` for my views:

```
class CertificateDetailApi(APIView):

    permission_classes = [IsCreator]

    class OutputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Certificate
            fields = ('__all__')

    def get(self, request, pk):
        certificate = get_object_or_404(Certificate, pk=pk)
        serializer = self.OutputSerializer(certificate)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my permissions:

```
class IsCreator(BasePermission):
    def check_object_permissions(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.created_by == request.user
```

My problem is that the `check_object_permissions()` method is never called.

What I have tried:

- To replace `APIView` by `GenericAPIView`
- To call `check_object_permissions()` in the view, before `return Response(serializer.data)`
- To implement `get_object()` method in the view

None of these solutions worked.

I don't understand what to call `check_object_permissions()`.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling wrong method as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

> To implement a custom permission, override BasePermission and
> implement either, or both, of the following methods:
>
> ```
> .has_permission(self, request, view)
> .has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)
> ```

So in your case

```
class IsCreator(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.created_by == request.user
```

Comment: It's work very well. Also, I had to add `self.check_object_permissions(request, certificate)` to my view.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace check_object_permission function to has_object_permission